# Loop for recent post on home page in django project

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to show 6 recent blog posts on home page in django project 
Nd 2nd doubt is that i want that like after 8-9posts  on blog page its will automatically create new page like in so many websites having option next page  page 1 as in picture[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOMpS.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you import timezone from django.utils

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

and you add a field "pub_date"

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

finally you filter your model 'objects.filter()' ordering them by date with a limit to 6

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(some_filters).oredr_by(pub_date)
```

you also need to take look a at the paginator class

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

> **As per your question, there could be two scenarios.**

```
Implementation for web and mobile clients
```

If you have to serve it via API's you need to use django-rest-framework and use **pageindex** and **pagesize** so that the client have the access to get the records as per the situation.
In django-rest-framework, there is in-built options for [Pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

Implementation for Django website

In this case, you have to use pagination template so that the requirement can be achieved.

***References:***
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/pagination/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/paginator/
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html
https://samulinatri.com/blog/django-pagination-tutorial/